# How to pass variables to gnome-terminal command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

I am trying to use variables to construct the `--command` arg for `gnome-terminal`.

My shell script look like this:

```
buildId="aa-bb-cc"
versionCode="123456"
daily="daily"

gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "while true; do
        python acra.py $versionCode $buildId 0 $daily
        sleep 600 # 10 mins
    done"'
```

But when I run this script, new terminal open but it cannot recognize these variables, I'm only receive `sys.argv = ['acra.py', '0']` inside my python script, so I guess the cmd was executed just like:

```
python acra.py 0
```

So how can I use variable in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `gnome-terminal` behaves like `xterm`:

```
gnome-terminal -e sh -c 'some commands here' sh "$variable1" "$variable2" "etc."
```

The strings at the end of the command line will be available inside the `sh -c` script as `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.  The first argument to the script, the string `sh`, will be placed in `$0` and used in error messages by the shell.

In your case:

```
#!/bin/sh

buildId="aa-bb-cc"
versionCode="123456"
daily="daily"

gnome-terminal -e sh -c '
    while true; do
        python acra.py "$1" "$2" 0 "$3"
        sleep 600
    done' sh "$versionCode" "$buildId" "$daily"
```

This assumes that the `acra.py` script is available in the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

[Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468733/383498) gives an error.

Using the `-x` option instead of the `-e` option, it will be fix error.

I used `echo` instead of `python` in the following examples for easy error detection.

```
buildId="aa-bb-cc"
versionCode="123456"
daily="daily"

gnome-terminal -e sh -c \
  'echo "$1" "$2" 0 "$3"; sleep 60' \
  sh "$versionCode" "$buildId" "$daily"
```

result is:
`Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option -c`

```
buildId="aa-bb-cc"
versionCode="123456"
daily="daily"

gnome-terminal -x sh -c \
  'echo "$1" "$2" 0 "$3"; sleep 60' \
  sh "$versionCode" "$buildId" "$daily"
```

Opens new terminal window, and print this result in new window : `123456 aa-bb-cc 0 daily`

> From `gnome-terminal` man page:
>
> -e, --command=STRING
>
> Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal.
>
> -x, --execute
>
> Execute the remainder of the command line inside the terminal.

The correct answer with [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) approach :

```
#!/bin/sh

buildId="aa-bb-cc"
versionCode="123456"
daily="daily"

gnome-terminal -x sh -c '
    while true; do
        python acra.py "$1" "$2" 0 "$3"
        sleep 600
    done' sh "$versionCode" "$buildId" "$daily"
```

Answer according to your ([nhoxbypass](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/310573/nhoxbypass)) example :

```
buildId="aa-bb-cc"
versionCode="123456"
daily="daily"

gnome-terminal -e "sh -c \"while true; do
        python acra.py $versionCode $buildId 0 $daily
        sleep 600 # 10 mins
    done\""
```

or

```
buildId="aa-bb-cc"
versionCode="123456"
daily="daily"

gnome-terminal -x sh -c "while true; do
        python acra.py $versionCode $buildId 0 $daily
        sleep 600 # 10 mins
    done"
```